# Finding the correct PORT on a PIC and implementation of a buzzer

Tags: c, port, hardware, pic

Afternoon all,

I am currently delving into the brand new world (to me anyway) of embedded systems and am struggling to understand something. I've looked around for an answer but either the answer is so staggeringly obvious that it's not implicitly stated or I am asking the wrong question.

The question is this; I have a QL200 development board which has several components I am interfacing with a PIC16F877A (Push buttons, LEDs, LCD screen and buzzer). The last component I am really struggling with is the buzzer.

Through some reading , I am led to believe that to make the buzzer sound I simply have to set the pin it is operating on high. However I am unsure how to do this. Furthermore, I have found (by luck or guidance) the ports that all the other components run on but I have no clue as to actually how they are assigned their ports. Is it by assigning them a port or are they set on a certain port as standard?

For example, my LCD panel is running off PORTD:

```
#define lcd PORTD

    void writeCommand(unsigned char ch)
{
    lcd = ch;
    RS = 0;
    RW =0;
    E = 1;
    lcdDelay();
    E=0;
}

void Init_lcd(void)
{
    ADCON1 = 0x07; //required setting of analog to digital
    TRISD = 0x00;
    TRISA1 = 0;
    TRISA2 = 0;
    TRISA3 = 0;

    writeCommand(0x0f);
    writeCommand(0x38); //set to two line mode
    clearDisplay();

    writeString("MAIN MENU");
}
```

Is that from a data sheet? I simply got told it was on PORTD so ran with that and it works.

However now it comes the turn of the buzzer and I'm stumped as to even get started. Several examples online use PORTB but I'm already using push buttons as inputs on PORTB:

```
#define TempButton1 RB1
#define TempButton2 RB2
#define TempButton3 RB3
```

Last thing, is that once I find the port the buzzer is running on, is it a simple matter of raising it high to get the buzzer to sound? i.e:

```
//declarations 
#define buzzer PORT(x)
//in a function somewhere
buzzer = 1; //hopefully buzzer should sound
```

A lot of my research indicates that this way should work but some use PMW and frequencies to achieve a sound. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It'a almost certain that you will have to toggle the output port pin at twice the frequency you desire, since this is also described as an audio and voice feature, so just enabling the output cannot do that. If it shares a port with other outputs, you must preserve the state of the other outputs while you toggle it. There is a section on the "beeper module" in [this datasheet](http://www.pic16.com/soft/QL200_user_a4_en.pdf) which says *"Examples of this module are contained in the CD-ROM."*

Comment: Good evening @WeatherVane, nice to see you again. From that datasheet it seems to indicate that the buzzer is connected via RC2. Indicating to me that it must be set thusly: #define buzzer RC2. Ill look into  setting RC2 low and high at a frequency that can be heard by humans and report back. Unfortunately I don't have access to the CD-ROM, otherwise this could have saved me a great deal of difficulty.

Comment: I saw hints in my delving that the connection port is optional, perhaps even configurable. Go study the examples supplied! **Edit:** oops you can't.

Comment: *"at a frequency that can be heard by humans"* you'll need an oscilloscpe if you are doing any serious work. Also useful for seeing port levels (in or out) at the chip.

Comment: And just like that it's working as desired. Thanks again for clear and concise feedback! It is certainly much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to toggle the output port pin at twice the frequency you desire, since this is also described as an audio and voice feature, and just enabling the output cannot do that. If it shares a port with other outputs, you must preserve the state of the other outputs while you toggle it.

If you don't have an oscilloscpe, get one if you are doing any serious work. Also useful for seeing port levels (in or out) at the chip.